# My array is being filled with random numbers instead of file numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, file, fstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
        int grades[30];
        int num = 0;
        ifstream inFile;
        inFile.open("grades.dat")
        while(inFile >> grades[num])
        {
                cout << grades[num] << endl;
                num++;
        }
        inFile.close();
return 0;
}
```

My code is giving me random numbers in the array like -98312 or 40124 and I do not know how to fix it.
grades.dat is just a simple text file with 5 numbers that I want to fill the array with and grades.dat looks like this.

100

95

87

90

76

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is precisely what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: Cannot reproduce http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0391d12ca66a23d

Comment: can we see a dump of the file please

Comment: The code in the question does not compile. Post a compileable [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. For some reason when i did num++; it would throw everything off and would give me random numbers for some reason. Once I deleted that line then everything ran smoothly.

Comment: If you make the code in the question compile by adding the missing `;`, it will work just fine **with** `num++`. If you remove `num++` you will read all the values into `grades[0]` so you couldn't print out the array afterwards. You are clearly not running the same code as you have posted in the question.

Answer (score -1):

the array was initially declared with 30 spots, if the grades.dat file only has 5, then entier grades[0]-grades[4] should be correct numbers, the rest of the array could be random numbers since you never cleared the array.
Try modifying to grades[30] = {0};

Comment: OP's code only outputs numbers that were successfully read from the file, so it doesn't appear to be an initialization problem.